# In IE Favicon Icon showing wrong

Tags: html, css

In IE for specific page it is showing wrong favicon. All the other pages showing correct icon. In other brower also it showing correct.
I did not get why this is happening. Any Idea..?

Thank you in advance.

I have attached the images that shows for wrong favicon.
[Wrong Favicon Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKJFe.png)
[image]

Comment: It would be really helpful if You can share code for FAV icon on the "Correct" page and on the "Wrong" page. There is probably typo or pointing to other page.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the code :
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/globals/img/icons/favicon.ico">
It is used in head of  index.html that is base for all pages..

Comment: Please confirm the line is same both files (eg.: index.html & other.html) and are these files in same folder?

Comment: I was facing this issue in production only. Locally every thing was working fine. 
I checked on production and there was an favicon in root directory and one at location that I have given in code. I did not get why this file was used by application as in code I have given the  ref="/assets/globals/img/icons/favicon.ico" .
But after deleting that file it works for me.

Thank you for support...